# How to make a function work with different sized meshgrid/linspace inputs

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I have a a function called `[U,V,W] = my_function(x,y,z)` which takes grid vectors as inputs and calculates some outputs evaluated at those grid points. There are `N` grid points in total.

The problem is that I want my function to be tolerant to different sizes of inputs. For example,

```
THIS:
[Y,Z] = meshgrid(0:10,-10:20); X = 6.3;

OR THIS:
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(0:10,-10:20,-2:2);

OR THIS:
Z = linspace(-1,1,10); X = 4.2; Y = 1;
etc
```

But inside the function I need to convert the x y z variables to to a 3 x `N` array like this:

```
r = [X(:) Y(:) Z(:)]
```

(this is because I need to apply some rotation matrices, and then do some further manipulation on the rotated coordinates). This does not work if X,Y, and Z are different sizes.

I have tried to make a helper function which pre-processes the coordinates, as shown in the MWE below, but it is quite messy. I wonder if there is a more succinct / cleaner / more standard way to achieve this?

```
x = linspace(-10,10,100);
Y = 3;
z = linspace(-12,12,80);
[X,Z] = meshgrid(x,z);

[U,V,W] = my_function(X,Y,Z);




%%% MAIN FUNCTION %%%
function [U,V,W] = my_function(X,Y,Z)

[X,Y,Z] = preprocess_gridvectors(X,Y,Z);  % Make sure grid vectors are all same size
N1 = size(X,1); N2 = size(X,2); N3 = size(X,3);
X = X(:); Y = Y(:); Z = Z(:);

%%% Do some transformation and processing here (rotate coordinates and use them)
R = [cos(pi) -sin(pi) 0;sin(pi) cos(pi) 0;0 0 1]; rotXYZ = R*[X Y Z].';
U = rotXYZ(1,:); V = rotXYZ(2,:); W = rotXYZ(3,:);
%%%

% Put the outputs back into the same shape as the original inputs
U = reshape(U, N1,N2,N3);
V = reshape(V, N1,N2,N3);
W = reshape(W, N1,N2,N3);
end



%%% HELPER FUNCTION %%%
function [X,Y,Z] = preprocess_gridvectors(X,Y,Z)

unique_array_sizes = unique([size(X) size(Y) size(Z)]);  % Determine dimensions to use
unique_array_sizes(unique_array_sizes==1) = [];          % Disregard scalar dimension
N_expected = prod(unique_array_sizes);                   % Total number of unique grid points expected

sizes = zeros(3,3);
if numel(X)==N_expected     % X already has the right dimensions
    sizes(1,1) = size(X,1); % Get the dimensions of X
    sizes(1,2) = size(X,2);
    sizes(1,3) = size(X,3);
end

if numel(Y)==N_expected    % Y already has the right dimensions
    sizes(2,1) = size(Y,1);
    sizes(2,2) = size(Y,2);
    sizes(2,3) = size(Y,3);
end

if numel(Z)==N_expected    % Z already has the right dimensions
    sizes(3,1) = size(Z,1);
    sizes(3,2) = size(Z,2);
    sizes(3,3) = size(Z,3);
end

inds = sizes~=0; % Anything which is non-zero has correct dimensions already
ind_dir = find(inds(:,1),1); % Choose the first axis that has good dimensions

% These should be the correct final dimensions now
N1 = sizes(ind_dir,1);
N2 = sizes(ind_dir,2);
N3 = sizes(ind_dir,3);

if ~any(sizes(1,:)) % X direction needs replicating
    X = repmat(X,[N1 N2 N3]);
end
if ~any(sizes(2,:)) % Y direction needs replicating
    Y = repmat(Y,[N1 N2 N3]);
end
if ~any(sizes(3,:)) % Z direction needs replicating
    Z = repmat(Z,[N1 N2 N3]);
end

end
```

Comment: Can we assume that in  each dimension the size of all inputs is either the same or 1? Apart from that, is the number of inputs fixed (3) or can it vary dynamically?

Comment: @LuisMendo The number of inputs is always fixed to be 3 (always x,y, and z have to be provided), and I am happy with how to catch those errors myself.

Comment: My first question was, for example: Can we assume `X = ones(10,20,30); Y = ones(10,1,30); Z = ones(1,20,40)` is not a possible input? (because `size(Z,3)` is `40` and not `30`)

Comment: @LuisMendo If, for example, the dimensions of one of the inputs is a 2D array (i.e. N1 x N2 x 1), then there should be at least another input which also has the same size (because they should have been generated with meshgrid).

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, I think the example you gave should not be allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get [implicit expansion](https://nhigham.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/) to do the work for you:

```
X = X + 0*Y + 0*Z;
Y = 0*X + Y + 0*Z;
Z = 0*X + 0*Y + Z;
```

This uses some unnecessary arithmetical operations (i.e. multiplying by 0 and then adding), but the computation time required for that is probably negligible.

Comment: I have to say, I actually laughed out loud when seeing this answer. Delighful. Thanks!

Comment: I had fun too, nice question!